# Is it better to store nested data or use flat structure with unique names in JSON?

Tags: json, elasticsearch, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

In simple words: Is

```
{
    "diary":{
        "number":100,
        "year":2006
    },
    "case":{
        "number":12345,
        "year":2006
    }
}
```

or

```
{
    "diary_number":100,
    "diary_year":2006,
    "case_number":12345,
    "case_year":2006

}
```

better when using Elasticsearch?

In my case total keys are only a few (10-15). Which is better performance wise?

**Use case** is displaying data from noSQL database (mostly dynamoDB). Also feeding it into Elasticsearch.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My rule of thumb -  if you would need to query/update nested fields, use flat structure.

If you use nested structure, then elastic will make it flat but then has an overhead of managing those relations. Performance wise - flat is always better since elastic doesnt need to related and find nested documents.

Here's an excerpt from [Managing Relations Inside Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/blog/managing-relations-inside-elasticsearch) which lists some disadvantages you might want to consider.

> Elasticsearch is still fundamentally flat, but it manages the nested
>   relation internally to give the appearance of nested hierarchy. When
>   you create a nested document, Elasticsearch actually indexes two
>   separate documents (root object and nested object), then relates the
>   two internally. Both docs are stored in the same Lucene block on the
>   same Shard, so read performance is still very fast.
>
> This arrangement does come with some disadvantages. Most obvious, you
>   can only access these nested documents using a special `nested
>   query`. Another big disadvantage comes when you need to update the
>   document, either the root or any of the objects.
>
> Since the docs are all stored in the same Lucene block, and Lucene
>   never allows random write access to it's segments, updating one field
>   in the nested doc will force a reindex of the entire document.
>
> This includes the root and any other nested objects, even if they were
>   not modified. Internally, ES will mark the old document as deleted,
>   update the field and then reindex everything into a new Lucene block.
>   If your data changes often, nested documents can have a non-negligible
>   overhead associated with reindexing.
>
> Lastly, it is not possible to "cross reference" between nested
>   documents. One nested doc cannot "see" another nested doc's
>   properties. For example, you are not able to filter on "A.name" but
>   facet on "B.age". You can get around this by using `include_in_root`,
>   which effectively copies the nested docs into the root, but this get's
>   you back to the problems of inner objects.

Answer (score 2):

Nested data is quite good. Unless you explicitly declare `diary` and `case` as [nested](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html) field, they will be indexed as [object](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/object.html) fields. So elasticsearch will convert them itself to

```
{
    "diary.number":100,
    "diary.year":2006,
    "case.number":12345,
    "case.year":2006

}
```

Consider also, that every field value in elasticsearch can be a [array](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/array.html). You need the `nested` datatype only if you have many diaries in a single document and need to "maintain the independence of each object in the array".

Answer (score 1):

The answer is a clear it-depends. JSON is famous for its nested structures. However, there are some tools which only can deal with key-value structures and flat JSONs and **I feel Elastic is more fun with flat JSONs, in particular if you use Logstash**, see e.g. https://discuss.elastic.co/t/what-is-the-best-way-of-getting-mongodb-data-into-elasticsearch/40840/5

I am happy to be proven wrong..

Comment: Nested are almost hidden document, use nested is very costly in the indexation / delete time. For query performance will be similar. In this topic's example, i will go flat for sure. Nested would be an option if there would be sub list items for exemple.